# Mistake with my routes for uploading an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, controller

I'm trying to solve a really simple problem with my code. I want to upload image into a post, I use paperclip, and the last step is not working.

That is my controller :

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all 
  end

  def new 
   @post = Post.new
  end

  def create 
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save 
    flash[:success] = "uccess!"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else 
    flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to new_post_path
  end 

  end 

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end



private 

def post_params 
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :image, :prix, :adress, :description)
end
end
```

that my form :

```html
<%= simple_form_for @post, url: root_path do |f|%>
<%= f.input :title, label: "Nom du plat" %>
<br>
<%= f.input :image, as: :file %>
<br>
<%= f.input :prix %>
<%= f.input :adress, label: "Localisation" %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<br>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

and that my view :

```html
<%= image_tag (@post.image.url(:medium)) %>
<br>

<%= @post.description %>
<br>

<button>
 <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>


</button>
```

So if you go through, and you spot a stupid mistake, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Comment: Well, when i want to validate the post content to create it, rails send me the error : No route matches [POST] "/"

Routes :
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts 

  root 'posts#index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `root_path` as the helper in your form when you need to call the route for post. Run rake routes and look for the create action related to post, which should be the same as the `get` route for the show action.

This should not be root_path:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, url: root_path do |f|%>
```

Comment: When i run rake routes, the only path which is empty is for create from post, so i try post_path posts_path, and after that, i can't open my page of creation for the new posts

Comment: update your question with the output of rake routes and I'll tell you what it should be

Comment: My mistake, i did nt try posts_path, and now = It's working !!!!
Thanks you a lot @toddmetheny

Comment: Sorry i don't understand really well english, i think you want that i put your answer into solution ?
How can i do that ?